# Formatting in glossaries is weird on same pages (but ok on others for some reason)

Tags: formatting, glossaries

I'm currently having a weird `glossaries`-Behaviour using the `super3col`-style  where the text goes too far to the right in my .tex document.

The Text goes into the right margin (click on images for higher resolution)

[image: working page]
[image: malfunctioning page]

**My [TeX File](http://pastebin.com/c7mDBRvK).**

[Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer) told me that this is the key that makes trouble:

```
\newglossaryentry{Mensch-Maschine Schnittstelle}
{name=Mensch-Maschine Schnittstelle,
 description={Eine Mensch-Maschine Schnittstelle dient zur besseren \gls{Befehl}sübertragung von Mensch zu Maschine. Wenn ich ein Text-Dokument abspeichern möchte, dann klicke ich in einem \gls{UI} einen Knopf mit der Beschriftung \textit{Speichern}. Sobald ich diesen Knopf drücke wird dies vom Computer registriert und er sendet mehrere \gls{Befehl}e an den Computer um die Datei zu speichern. Ich als \gls{User} muss nicht wissen, wie diese \gls{Befehl}e heißen oder was sie tun, schließlich habe ich den Knopf, der die Verbindung zwischen der Computer-Welt und der dem Menschen begreiflichen Welt aufbaut.}
}
```

He told me that I should use a `\parbox` but this created [these compiler errors](http://pastebin.com/ptUhSeBP).

I hope this Information is enough to help you guys solving my problem. I'd be really thankful if you wizards could help me here :)

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what the problem is.

Comment: @egreg: I think the OP refers to the bleeding of the content into the right margin

Comment: Are you aware that even the first screen shot of the 'functioning' page is actually wrong: The glossary description bleed into the margins as well. You have to reduce the `\glsdescwidth` length

Comment: Oh I choose that because I liked it. But you're right. The Header is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole problem is, that the glossary key `Mensch - Maschinen  Schnittstelle` is just too wide for the `super3col` glossary style.
If I understand `glossaries-user.pdf` correctly, the width of first column for the given style is just used from the longest entry, which is `Mensch - Maschinen Schnittstelle`, shifting the 2nd column far the right and causing the bleeding of content into the (right) margin.

The key should be wrapped using a `\parbox[t]{2cm}{...}` for example (`t` for top alignment)

However,

```
\setlength\glsdescwidth{0.8\hsize}
```

is too wide as well. I changed it to

```
\setlength\glsdescwidth{0.6\hsize}
```

(I renamed the glossary file to `glossarynew.tex`, since I've got an important `glossary.tex` in my SX sandbox directory ;-))

```
\documentclass[
 fontsize=11pt,
 a4paper,
 pdflatex,twoside
 ]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\inputencoding{latin1}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp, lmodern, fancyhdr, microtype}


\usepackage[xindy,
            style=super3col,
            toc,
            nonumberlist,
            section]{glossaries}


{\inputencoding{utf8}\input{glossarynew.tex}}
\makenoidxglossaries    

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,
            right=5.5cm,
            top=2.5cm,
            bottom=2.5cm]
            {geometry}


%I keep this in because I'm changing page behaviour. maybe this helps you guys
\usepackage{todonotes}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{5cm}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Blindtext}
\Blindtext

\clearpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newgeometry{left=2cm,
             right=2cm,
             top=2cm,
             bottom=2cm}

%add all Glossary entries (generates weird whitepsace if made before glossary)
\glsaddall

%Prepare for Glossary   
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\glsdescwidth{0.6\hsize}

%Print Glossary
\printnoidxglossaries
\clearpage  

\end{document}
```

**glossarynew.tex**

```
\newglossaryentry{Mensch-Maschine Schnittstelle}
{name=\parbox[t]{2cm}{Mensch-Maschine Schnittstelle},
 description={Eine Mensch-Maschine Schnittstelle dient zur besseren \gls{Befehl}sübertragung von Mensch zu Maschine. Wenn ich ein Text-Dokument abspeichern möchte, dann klicke ich in einem \gls{UI} einen Knopf mit der Beschriftung \textit{Speichern}. Sobald ich diesen Knopf drücke wird dies vom Computer registriert und er sendet mehrere \gls{Befehl}e an den Computer um die Datei zu speichern. Ich als \gls{User} muss nicht wissen, wie diese \gls{Befehl}e heißen oder was sie tun, schließlich habe ich den Knopf, der die Verbindung zwischen der Computer-Welt und der dem Menschen begreiflichen Welt aufbaut.}
}

\newglossaryentry{Prozess}
{name=Prozess,
 description={Jedes laufende Computerprogramm hat seinen eigenen Prozess. Prozesse sind diese Listeinträge die man unter Windows im Task Manager sehen kann. Wenn man z. B. Firefox geöffnet habe dann läuft dahinter der Prozess \texttt{firefox.exe}}
}

\newglossaryentry{Administrator}
{name=Administrator,
 description={Der Administrator ist auf -Computern der Nutzer mit den wenigsten Einschränkungen. Das macht den Administrator-Account besonders attraktiv für \gls{Malware}-Attacken.}
}

\newglossaryentry{Adware}
{name=Adware,
 description={\gls{Malware} welche sich zusammen mit anderen Programmen installiert. Kofferwort aus \underline{ad}vertisement (Werbung) und Soft\underline{ware}.}
}


\newglossaryentry{Malware}
{name=Adware,
 description={\gls{Malware} welche sich zusammen mit anderen Programmen installiert. Kofferwort aus \underline{ad}vertisement (Werbung) und Soft\underline{ware}.}
}

\newglossaryentry{Befehl}
{name=Adware,
 description={\gls{Malware} welche sich zusammen mit anderen Programmen installiert. Kofferwort aus \underline{ad}vertisement (Werbung) und Soft\underline{ware}.}
}

\newglossaryentry{UI}
{name=Adware,
 description={\gls{Malware} welche sich zusammen mit anderen Programmen installiert. Kofferwort aus \underline{ad}vertisement (Werbung) und Soft\underline{ware}.}
}


\newglossaryentry{User}
{name=Adware,
 description={\gls{Malware} welche sich zusammen mit anderen Programmen installiert. Kofferwort aus \underline{ad}vertisement (Werbung) und Soft\underline{ware}.}
}
```

[image]

Comment: [He shows me some errors](https://i.imgur.com/b6XjBRp.png) because of the `\parbox` [.log](http://pastebin.com/ptUhSeBP)

Comment: @JonasDralle: Works for me out of the box.

Comment: Did you clean the old *.aux etc. files and recompile?

Comment: Cleaned everythign until only .tex and .bib files were left. Stil get the same errros. It's partly because of *! Illegal parameter number in definition of \glo@Mensch-Maschine Schnittstelle@text.*. I'm sorry but I cannot see the Problem. He told me to use parbox, it works for him, not for me, but ge gotta be right because he has wayy more experience that I have

Comment: @JonasDralle: Can you send me your files by mail? I won't publish it of course!

Comment: I hope its ok for you when i send it via Mail to kontakt@siebenfelsen.de using a mega.co.nz download link (so it wont spam your mail space) and because you have a faily german name and a german email adress I'll write it in german, my fellow Kollege :P

Comment: @JonasDralle: I've got your mail (and I am German ;-)). I'll tested it and unfortunately (!!!) I can compile your document out of the box. I suspect some version mismatch in a package or something else. I've used `TeXLive 2015` so it's quite new. You should look after the `glossaries` version -- my version is from 2015/03/16, but I can't say that it's a `glossaries` issue at all

Comment: welp. I've got `2015-03-20 22:00:01` and I'm pretty sure that they wont change their whole system in just 4 days. Thanks for all your help. I will shorten that glossary entry

Comment: @JonasDralle: Happy TeXing then... and you know the contact mail ;-)